# get image from thumbnails query on android

Tags: android, image-processing

I have this code (found on this site, somewhere):

```
    public static List<MyImages> getImages(Activity context) {
    List<MyImages> lst = new ArrayList<MyImages>();
    Cursor cursor = getCameraThumbImages(context);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int columnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        int columnIndexPath = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
        int columnIndexImagePath = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);

            int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            String path = cursor.getString(columnIndexPath);
            Uri imgThmbPath = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                            + imageID);
            String hope = cursor.getString(columnIndexImagePath);
            MyImages p2p = new MyImages(path, "" + imageID);
            lst.add(p2p);
        }
    }

    return lst;
}
```

This code allow me to access the thumbnails of the images on my phone. The issue is that I don't see how to get the original image path from this.

The question is: given the thumbnail (or the cursor), how do i get the original image path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In thumbnail you have MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID field, you can obtain related image id from it. Than make a query to MediaStore.Images.Media and get path to your photo from MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA field.

**EDIT**

```
// First request thumbnails what you want
String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID};
Cursor thumbnails = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

// Then walk thru result and obtain imageId from records
for (thumbnails.moveToFirst(); !thumbnails.isAfterLast(); thumbnails.moveToNext()) {
    String imageId = thumbnails.getString(thumbnails.getColumnIndex(Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));

    // Request image related to this thumbnail 
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor images = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, filePathColumn, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", new String[] {imageId}, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // Your file-path will be here
        String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]));
    }

}

//Of course you need to restrict queries using selection and selection args params and get only rows that you really need
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you, please, give me the code that does this (or a link to some code)? I don't fully understand how to do the query. Thanks again.

Comment: Do queries as usual with content provider

Comment: thanks. I'll check your code and let you know if it solves my issue.